# When exactly does Google Guice build @Singleton bindings lazily?

Tags: java, binding, guice

From the documentation [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes#user-content-applying-scopes):

The only time @Singleton will be lazily initialized (with stage set to PRODUCTION) is below:

- Guice will only eagerly build singletons for the types it knows about. These are the types mentioned in your modules, plus the transitive dependencies of those types.

I don't think I understand that statement. In my case, all the types are already known at compile time.

I have a Module class (that extends AbstractModule), and it declares a lot of bindings via methods annotated with `@Provides @Singleton @Named(...)`.

And they're all getting created lazily. I want this to happen eagerly (at application startup). What do I need to do here? (I have to use @Singleton annotation for certain reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/google/guice/issues/216), you cannot do it out of the box using `@Provides`-style bindings. You can use `Provider` approach mentioned in the issue:

```java
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

  static class MyProvider implements Provider<Foo> {
    @Inject Bar bar;
    @Inject Baz baz;

    public Foo get() {
      return Foo.from(bar, baz);
    }
  }

  public void configure() {
    bind(Foo.class).toProvider(MyProvider.class).asEagerSingleton();
  }
}
```